# Обработка результата после вычисления факториала

Tags: java, циклы

Столкнулся с проблемой, что если высчитывать факториал более 20! , то значение записывающееся в переменную "ret" вместо ексепшена выдает некорректное значение с отброшенными цифрами или отрицательное. Инетересно решить проблему не прибегая к использованию BigInteger или через возврат значения в double. Пробовал преобразовывать сначала double в String через if, аля

```
String rez = String.valueOf(ret);
   if (parseDouble(rez) <= Long.MAX_VALUE) {
   System.out.println(num + "! = " + rez);
   } else if (parseDouble(rez) > Long.MAX_VALUE){
     System.out.println("We have a number bigger than 9223372036854775807!");
   }
```

но ничего не получалось.
Как тут на выходе получить long с ограничением, что если число больше long - держи сообщение "We have a number bigger than 9223372036854775807!" ?

```
    public class Factorial {
    public long fact(int num) {
/**
 * if number<0 -> sout message
 * if number>=0 -> calculate factorial
 * if result number is too large -> we use "long" type
 */
        if (num < 0) {
            System.out.println("Your number is less then 0");
        } else if (num >= 0) {
            long ret = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i) ret *= i;
            System.out.println(num + "! = " + ret);
            return ret;
        }
        return 77;
    }
}
```

вызов в мейне

```
Factorial factorial = new Factorial();
factorial.fact(21);
```

Comment: бросай ексепшин на входе если переданное число больше 20

Comment: похоже это пока что самый практичный вариант

Comment: Ну и немного по самому коду вычисления факториала: 1). Почему если `num` меньше нуля, то возвращается `77`? Я бы понял `1`, `0` или `-1`, но не `77`. 2). `else if (num >= 0)` - `if` здесь не нужен. 3). Нет смысла начинать `i` с `1` - имеет смысл начинать с `2`.

Comment: @Regent 77 - хорошее значение, так как нет числа, факториал которого равен 77 :)

Comment: на самом деле, думаю, нужно было написать метод через void, а так return прикрепил, поскольку проходил как раз такой материал. Так что это больше для себя, чем для практического использования

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока что только такой вариант более менее отвечает моему замыслу, хотя и грубовато как то...

```
public class Factorial {
    public long fact(int num) {
/**
 * if number<0 -> sout message
 * if number>=0 -> calculate factorial
 * if result number is too large -> we use "long" type
 */
        if (num < 0) {
            System.out.println("Your number is less then 0");
        } else if (num >= 0 & num <= 20) {
            long ret = 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i) ret *= i;
            System.out.println(num + "! = " + ret);
            return ret;
        } else if (num > 20) {
            System.out.println("We have a number bigger than a Long.MAX_VALUE -> 9223372036854775807!");
        } else System.out.println("Something goes wrong!!!");
        return 77;
    }
}
```

ну и вызов в мейне

```
Factorial factorial = new Factorial();
factorial.fact(22);
```